# Is it possible to mask CALayer that is itself a mask of another layer?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, calayer

The title has it. `CALayer` has property `mask` that is of type `CALayer`. So I have layer A that I want to mask with layer B. Then I want to mask layer B with layer C. It is surely posible to assign values to properties like that. The question is would the layer C influence how layer A is rendered?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @matt Tried it some time ago but it did not work. I might have made a mystake or there might be some other way (e.g. some combination with `maskView` property of `UIView`). Looking for advice of somebody more experienced or somebody who already made it work.

Comment: No, I think your experiment is correct. You can use a mask or clipping as you _construct_ a layer that will be a mask, but a mask layer cannot actively _have_ a mask layer.

Comment: @matt Perhaps there is another way how to combine 2 masks in logical AND or XOR manner (both AND and XOR would do). Using `CAShapeLayer` with `usesEvenOddFillRule` does not work in this case due to low performance when changing and redrawing mask. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35762289/311865 - motivation for this question.